# Java MongoClient - Type exceptions when using Aggregate

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am getting the following `exception`:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "192.168.3.25:27017" , 
         "errmsg" : "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array,
          but was of type: EOO" , "code" : 17124 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

Whenever I run this pipeline using the `MongoClient` driver for `Java`:

```
[{ "$match" : { "_id" : "1"}}, { "$project" : { "count" : { "$size" : "$tags"}}}]
```

---

*What is causing this? The pipeline works fine in the `Mongo` shell?*

#### Here is my `Java` code:

```
  private void countArrayLength(String id, String arrayName) {

      AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().build(); 

      DBObject matchFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", id);
      DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", matchFields);

      DBObject projectCount = new BasicDBObject("$size", "$" + arrayName);
      DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("count", projectCount);
      DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);

      Cursor cursor = db.getCollection(collectionName)
                        .aggregate(asList(match, project), options);
}
```

#### DB Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "_class" : "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject",
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "tag" : "tagName"
        }, 
        {
            "tag" : "tagName"
        }, 
        {
            "tag" : "tagName"
        }, 
        {
            "tag" : "tagName"
        },
        {
            "tag" : "tagName"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show your db structure.

Comment: what is `$arrayName` in your query? Should not it be `$tags` ?

Comment: arrayName is passed into the method as a variable, so it does match the array name in the document

Comment: perhaps obvious but are you sure arrayName = "$tags" in the code when you debug? cuz you get that error typically when the field is undefined. null in other words

Comment: Yeah absolutely, I copied the pipeline straight from the Java implementation into the Mongo Shell and it worked.

Comment: right. when you execute on shell, i'm presuming array has values and not empty?

Comment: Yeah, always populated

Comment: Hm! weird. could be something very silly. version of the driver?

Comment: Yeah, it's a strange one, version: 2.14.2

Comment: you probably could try breaking down the query in java code a bit (of course if you haven't done it already). strip off project part in java code and see if the collection returns values. could be something to do with the way driver is trying to execute it.